# Appending JSON objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON objects being created dynamically as:

```
[{"fill":"none","stroke":"#000000","path":"M186.5,25L187.5,25L187.5,26L188.5,27L189.5,28L189.5,29L190.5,29","stroke-opacity":1,"stroke-width":5,"stroke-linecap":"round","stroke-linejoin":"round","transform":[],"type":"path"}]

[{"fill":"none","stroke":"#000000","path":"M73.5,42L73.5,42L75.5,43L82.5,46L101.5,55L119.5,65L126.5,69L128.5,71L129.5,71","stroke-opacity":1,"stroke-width":5,"stroke-linecap":"round","stroke-linejoin":"round","transform":[],"type":"path"}]

.......
```

I want to append all these Objects being generated into a single Javascript object as :

```
[{"fill":"none","stroke":"#000000","path":"M186.5,25L187.5,25L187.5,26L188.5,27L189.5,28L189.5,29L190.5,29","stroke-opacity":1,"stroke-width":5,"stroke-linecap":"round","stroke-linejoin":"round","transform":[],"type":"path"},
{"fill":"none","stroke":"#000000","path":"M73.5,42L73.5,42L75.5,43L82.5,46L101.5,55L119.5,65L126.5,69L128.5,71L129.5,71","stroke-opacity":1,"stroke-width":5,"stroke-linecap":"round","stroke-linejoin":"round","transform":[],"type":"path"}]
```

In this way every object being created should be appended to this JSON string.
I am able to concatenate two JSON objects and have it in a different Javascript variable as:

```
var obj1 = '[{"fill":"none","stroke":"#000000","path":"M186.5,25L187.5,25L187.5,26L188.5,27L189.5,28L189.5,29L190.5,29","stroke-opacity":1,"stroke-width":5,"stroke-linecap":"round","stroke-linejoin":"round","transform":[],"type":"path"}]';

var obj2 = '[{"fill":"none","stroke":"#000000","path":"M186.5,25L187.5,25L187.5,26L188.5,27L189.5,28L189.5,29L190.5,29","stroke-opacity":1,"stroke-width":5,"stroke-linecap":"round","stroke-linejoin":"round","transform":[],"type":"path"}]';

var mergedJS = JSON.parse(obj1).concat(JSON.parse(obj2));

  mergedJSON =JSON.stringify(mergedJS);
```

I however, want all the newly generated JSON objs in the same variable.
Could anyone please let me know how can I do this?

Comment: How are these objects generated? Can't you push them on an array directly?

Comment: I cannot push them directly to a array, because they are generated individually out of a function call.
If possible how can I push them into an array directly?

Comment: But this function gets called, and does it return the objects? Where do theses objects live?

Comment: Use `var mergedJS = JSON.parse(obj1).concat(JSON.parse(obj2));`

Comment: Yes, these objects are created as $("#data2").val(sketchpad.json()); and are assigned to a hidden div with ID = "data2"

Comment: @drkunibar: I havve done that. Was a typo in the question, corrected it Thanks!!

Comment: `var merged = []` and every time `#data2` changes `merged = merged.concat($('#data2').val());`

Comment: Each time you get a new object, call `JSON.parse`, and add it to the array. When you're done you'll have an array of all the objects.

Comment: I have done this: var arr= [];arr.push($("#data2").val(sketchpad.json()));
But I when I JSON.stringify(arr), it gives Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pull the objects out of their individual arrays before adding them to the master array:

```
var newJSArray = [];
var mergedJS = JSON.parse(obj1);
newJSArray.push(mergedJS[0]);
mergedJS = JSON.parse(obj2);
newJSArray.push(mergedJS[0]);
```

Obviously for n objects you'll be looping that instead of as I've done above.

Comment: I want every object being created being added to the array at that moment.

Comment: This code will accomplish the same thing. Just grab the 0-th element of each object array since your objects are being sent in an enclosing array.